# mysql replication table with different charsets

Tags: mysql

We have mysql cluster which includes master, slave and hot standby. There is a table which has 30 million records and the charset of the table is utf8. I want to update the charset of these tables to utf8mb4 charset without taking the downtime and without breaking the replication also. Please let me know if there is anyway to perform this activity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To other readers, if you plan on using a scheme involving updating a slave, failing over, then updating an old master (as I planned to do), you need to be aware of this issue: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percona provides a free tool for this purpose called [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html).

What it does, is to create a copy of your table and some triggers on your original table. The triggers copy data into the backup while your operation is running. When it's done, the two tables get swapped in an atomic way. No downtime, no data-loss. But make sure, you have no triggers already on the table.

Comment: I heard of this tool. But I have couple of doubts. Those are 1. how much time will it take for around 100GB of data ?, 2. At the time of this operation, what kind of data will be served (stale/fresh) ? 3. do you mean that backup table has new schema ?

Comment: 1. Doesn't matter, you don't have to care and actually you don't have a choice. It takes as long as it takes. 2. Fresh of course. Like I said your database will work as normal. Just the data that is inserted/updated/deleted into/from your table, will be inserted/updated/deleted in the backup table as well, as long as the operation lasts. 3. The table will have the same schema as your original table. It's a copy.

Comment: What about master-slave replication ? will replication happen automatically or should i run separately on slave as well ?

Comment: Replication will happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

the query will be

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;
```

Comment: But it will block the table. I want to perform this without blocking also

Comment: yes, but you need to wait for it because changing in any table will block the entire table till you get the result. How much time it will take to execute query.